# how can i trigger OnChangeFile input without Button Click in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to upload files to AWS but I don't want to press the  "choose file" button. it should automatically trigger is there any way to achieve this

in my .html file

```html
<div class="content">
  <input (change)="onChangeFile($event)" type="file" />
</div>
```

in my .ts file

```js
 async onChangeFile(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.fileSelected = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(environment);
    console.log('Uploaded');
    await this.S3CustomClient.uploadFile(
     .uploadFile(this.fileSelected, this.fileSelected.type, undefined, this.fileSelected.name, "private")
      .then((data: UploadResponse) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err: any) => console.error(err))
```

Comment: When do you want to trigger the upload? Could you elaborate on what you mean by "automatically trigger"?

Comment: when we click choose button a file chooser dialog will open can we automatically trigger the choose button without clicking ? @SeanAnglim

Comment: Ok and do you want the file chooser window to open automatically as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes @SeanAnglim

Comment: So that behaviour is not possible. It is considered as not secure and blocked until user interaction occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons a file chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation - so for example click event. What you want is not possible.